# Pandas KeyError in Kaggle set

Tags: python, pandas, keyerror

I am new to pandas and manipulated some internet code to work with this [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/uom190346a/sleep-health-and-lifestyle-dataset?resource=download). I made minor adjustments to the dataset (broke down pressure to two columns, rename headers, etc) and spend some reasonable time debugging. I cannot get this code to work, I always get a KeyError for the 'Sex' column:

```
import pandas
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pandas.read_csv("Data.csv", sep=";", index_col='ID')
#print(f"df is {type(df)} type")
features = ['ID','Sex','Age','Occupation','Sleep_Duration','Quality_of_Sleep','Physical_Activity_Level','Stress_Level','BMI_Category','Systolic_Blood_Pressure','Diastolic_Blood_Pressure','Heart_Rate','Daily_Steps','Sleep_Disorder']
df
h = df.head().values.tolist()

#for c in df.columns: print(c)
print(df['Sex'].head(10))

a = {'Male': 1, 'Female': 0}
df['Sex'] = df['Sex'].map(a)
b = {'Nurse': 0, 'Software Engineer': 1, 'Doctor': 2, 'Sales Representative': 3, 'Teacher': 4, 'Engineer': 5, 'Accountant': 6, 'Scientist': 7, 'Lawyer': 8, 'Salesperson': 9, 'Manager': 10}
df['Occupation'] = df['Occupation'].map(b)
c = {'Normal': 1, 'Overweight': 0, 'Obese': 2}
df['BMI_Category'] = df['BMI_Category'].map(c)
e = {'None': 0, 'Sleep_Apnea': 1, 'Insomnia': 2}
df['Sleep_Disorder'] = df['Sleep_Disorder'].map(e)


X = df[features]
Y = df['Sex']

dtree = DecisionTreeClassifier()
dtree = dtree.fit(X, Y)

tree.plot_tree(dtree, feature_names=features)
```

I tried renaming the headers, removing columns and I am still a bit dumbfounded why would some columns print, others won't.

Comment: Hi can you add [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and the full error stack?

Comment: There is not enough info to get specific here. So A "KeyError" occurs when you attempt to access a dictionary-like object (such as a DataFrame or a Series) using a key (usually a column label) that doesn't exist in the object (DataFrame).

Comment: It´s very common that the column names or "keys" have blank spaces, so you can try printing the names with print(df.columns) and you can see exactly the name of the column

Comment: The name of the columns is right, I triple checked it. The code is the above. A snippet of the Data.csv follows:      ID;Sex;Age;Occupation;Sleep_Duration;Quality_of_Sleep;Physical_Activity_Level;Stress_Level;BMI_Category;Systolic_Blood_Pressure;Diastolic_Blood_Pressure;Heart_Rate;Daily_Steps;Sleep_Disorder
1;Male;27;Software Engineer;6.1;6;42;6;Overweight;126;83;77;4200;None
2;Male;28;Doctor;6.2;6;60;8;Normal;125;80;75;10000;None
3;Male;28;Doctor;6.2;6;60;8;Normal;125;80;75;10000;None